# Horizontal Transformation on Linear Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a function $f(x)=0.5x+2$. The function is then translated to the following function $g(x)=0.5x-1$.  In the learning management software that my student is using they are expressing that a transformation of $g(x)=f(x-k)$ occurs that I know is a horizontal transformation. I put both equations in the following format:
$$g(x)=0.5(x-2)$$
$$f(x)=0.5(x-(-4))$$

When I plot both of them I noticed that one shifts 6 units to the right. How do I find the value of k, and units shifted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, say,  the  point $P= (2, f(2)) = (2, \frac 12 (2)  +2)= (2, 3) $ lying on the graph of function $f$.

By the transformation of function $f$ into function $g$, point $P$ will be horizontally transformed into a point $P'= (a, g(a))$ having the same $y$-coordinate as $P$ , but a different $x$-coordinate .

So , $$P' = ( a, g(a))= (a, f(2))= (a, 3)$$.

We therefore know that $g(a) = 3$ , or, equivalently :

$$\frac 12 a -1 =3  , \text {implying that} \space \space a = 8$$ .

With this we can calculate the $\Delta(x)$ , the change in $x-$ coordinate from $P= (2,3) $ to $P'= (8,3) $ :

$$\Delta(x)= x_{P'} - x_{P} = 8-2 = 6 $$.

So, in being transformed into $P'$, point $P$ has moved horizontally $6$ units to the right.

Since $P$ was arbitrary, the same thing holds for all points lying on the graph of function $f$ when $f$ is transformed into $g$ : every point lying on the graph of $f$ will be shifted $6$ units to the right when $f$ is  transformed into $g$.

Because a horizontal shift of $k$ units to the right is expressed by :

$$g (x)= f( x-k) , $$

we can say that :

$$k= 6.$$

Answer (score 1):

Please advise if I am misinterpreting the problem.  It seems as if you need to solve for $(k)$ to satisfy

$$(0.5)(x - k) + 2 = 0.5(x) - 1 \implies $$

$$(0.5)(-k) + 2 = (-1) \implies $$

$$(0.5)(-k) = -3 \implies k = 6.$$

---

Assuming that I have not misinterpreted the problem, the problem can alternatively be attacked with intuition, rather than Algebra.

The graph of $g(x)$ is (in effect) exactly $(3)$ units (vertically) less than the graph of $f(x)$.  That is, the entire graph of $f(x)$ has been shifted down three units.

So, you can intuitively calculate $(k)$ as the Real number necessary so that when the scalar of $(0.5)$ is applied to $(k)$, the result is a deduction of $(3)$ units.